# How do i get an age according to the current system time in NLS_DATE_FORMAT? (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, systimestamp

I have a table called person, how do i get a person age according to the current system time in NLS_DATE_FORMAT?

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY';

CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id      NUMBER (9),
  birthday       DATE CONSTRAINT nn_person_birthday NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

Note: I just want the exact age, not months neither days. Example Age: 43

Note2: I insert birthday like this in my table: TO_DATE('17.05.2003','DD.MM.YYYY')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format doesn't matter.  I would suggest:

```
floor(months_between(sysdate, p.birthday) / 12)
```